# IntelliJ IDEA 10 shows strange empty Debug window on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am a begginner IntelliJ IDEA user.
After updating to ver. 10.x I noticed a strange behaviour while debugging my Java code.
When I start debugging this artefact appeares on my screen:

http://habreffect.ru/files/34d/b1625c370/screen.png

It´s an empty window (always on top), and I can't close it.
I searched for some info about it on Google, but failed to find similar problems.

Current IDE version: 102.149

OS version: Ubuntu Linux 10.04

So, what is it and how can I switch this window off? Or this is a bug and I should write a bug report to JetBrains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some detached debugger panel with empty content. Not sure how you've managed to get it. Deleting ~/.IntelliJIdea10/config/runner.layout.xml and /.idea/workspace.xml or .iws file should help. You can also try to move ~/.IntelliJIdea10 directory to start with all the defaults and try it with the new project in case the first suggestion doesn't work. Otherwise file a bug to the issue tracker with the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, deleting ~/.IntelliJIdea10/config/option/runner.layout.xml solves the problem. Thank you!